# Syntax in R, Overtime Pay

Tags: r, syntax

I am an intro into computer science student and have learned more on how to use python and am now learning R. I'm not used to R, and I've figured out how to calculate overtime pay, but I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax:

```
computePay <- function(pay,hours){
}if (hours)>=40{
newpay = 40-hours
total=pay*1.5
return(pay*40)+newpay*total
}else{
return (pay * hours)
}
```

How would I code this correctly?

Comment: For starters, you should put the code for you function inside `{}`, not after `{}`. You might want to think about you other parentheses too. For example, `return()` will return the value in parentheses and not consider stuff after the `)`. `if(hours)` will test whether `hours` is truthy (non-zero) or falsy (0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at things like *vectorization*, a direct correction of your function would look something like:

```
computePay <- function(pay,hours) {
  if (hours >= 40) {
    newpay = hours - 40
    total = pay * 1.5
    return(pay*40 + newpay*total)
  } else {
    return(pay * hours)
  }
}
```

This supports calling the function with a single `pay` and a single `hours`. You mis-calculated `newpay` (which really should be named something `overhours`), I corrected it.

You may hear people talk about "avoiding magic constants". A "magic constant" is a hard-coded number within code that is not perfectly clear and/or might be useful to allow the caller to modify. For instance, in some contracts it might be that overtime starts at a number other than 40, so that might be configurable. You can do that by changing the formals to:

```
computePay <- function(pay, hours, overtime_hours = 40, overtime_factor = 1.5)
```

and using those variables instead of hard-coded numbers. This allows the user to specify other values, but if not provided then they resort to sane defaults.

Furthermore, it might be useful to call it with a vector of one or the other, in which case the current function will fail because `if (hours >= 40)` needs a single logical value, but (e.g.) `c(40,50) >= 40` returns a logical vector of length 2. We do this by introducing the `ifelse` function. Though it has some gotchas in advanced usage, it should work just fine here:

```
computePay1 <- function(pay, hours, overtime_hours = 40, overtime_factor = 1.5) {
  ifelse(hours >= overtime_hours,
         overtime_hours * pay + (hours - overtime_hours) * overtime_factor * pay,
         pay * hours)
}
```

Because of some gotchas and deep-nested readability (I've seen `ifelse` stacked 12 levels deep), some people prefer other solutions. If you look at it closer, you may find that you can take further advantage of vectorization and `pmax` which is `max` applied piece-wise over each element. (Note the difference of `max(c(1,3,5), c(2,4,4))` versus `pmax(c(1,3,5), c(2,4,4))`.)

Try something like this:

```
computePay2 <- function(pay, hours, overtime_hours = 40, overtime_factor = 1.5) {
  pmax(0, hours - overtime_hours) * overtime_factor * pay +
    pmin(hours, overtime_hours) * pay
}
```

To show how this works, I'll expand the `pmax` and `pmin` components:

```
hours <- c(20, 39, 41, 50)
overtime_hours <- 40
pmax(0, hours - overtime_hours)
# [1]  0  0  1 10
pmin(hours, overtime_hours)
# [1] 20 39 40 40
```

The rest sorts itself out.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Your "newpay*total" expression is outside the return command. You need put it inside the parentheses. The end bracket at the beginning of the second line should be moved to the last line. You also should have "(hours>=40)" rather than "(hours)>=40". Stylistically, the variable names are poorly chosen and there's no indentation (this might have helped you notice the misplaced bracket). Also, the calculation can be simplified:

```
total_pay = hourly_wage*(hours+max(0,hours-40)/2))
```

For every hour you work, you get your hourly wage. For every hour over 40 hours, you get your hourly wage plus half your hourly wage. So the total pay is wage*(total hours + (hours over 40)/2). Hours over 40 is either going to be total hours minus 40, or zero, whichever is larger.

Comment: Thank you! I first started learning python in class, and am still getting used to R syntax.